# Trying to add one gap in Bartender Template Designer

Tags: bartender

I am using Bartender 2022 R7 Automation Edition and I am trying to build a template but I cannot figure out how to add one single gap after row 5. Setting a gap manually in the page setup wizard, it wants to add the gap in every location. These labels are used for grocery store shelf tags.

[image: Label Stock]